# VBA Error 424, Writing value to a cell using ".Value" property

Tags: vba, excel, range

I'm a VBA newbie, and still confused about the difference between using a variable with/without the .Value property. From what I can tell, in order to write a value to a cell, you have to use the .Value property of a Range object? I get an error 424 when trying to write variables pos1 and pos2 to their specific cells near the bottom of this subfunction. What is wrong here, and is there a better way to write values to cells?

```
Sub Calcs1()
Sheets("Calculations").Select
Sheets("Calculations").Range("P1", Range("P1").End(xlDown)).Clear
Sheets("Calculations").Range("Q1", Range("Q1").End(xlDown)).Clear
Sheets("Calculations").Range("R1", Range("R1").End(xlDown)).Clear
Set l = Range("length")
Sheets("Calculations").Range("P1") = -l

Set incr = Range("incr")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim I As Long
For I = 2 To (2 * l / incr + 1)
    Cells(I, 16).Value = Sheets("Calculations").Range("P1") + (I - 1) * incr
Next I

LastRow = Sheets("Calculations").Range("P1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

Set pos = Sheets("Calculations").Range("P1:P" & LastRow)
Set V = Range("v")
Set m = Range("m")
Set cpos = Range("currpos")
Set mvals = Sheets("Calculations").Range("Q1:Q" & LastRow)
Set vvals = Sheets("Calculations").Range("R1:R" & LastRow)
Set mmax = Range("mmax")
Set vmax = Range("vmax")
Set pos1 = Range("posmmax")
Set pos2 = Range("posvmax")

Dim NumRows As Long
NumRows = pos.Rows.Count

Dim ii As Long
For ii = 1 To NumRows
    cpos.Value = Round(pos(ii) * (1 / incr), 0) / (1 / incr)
    mvals(ii).Value = m
    vvals(ii).Value = V
Next ii

mmax.Value = Application.Max(mvals)
vmax.Value = Application.Max(vvals)

pos1 = -l
pos2 = -l

Dim jj As Long
For jj = 1 To NumRows
    If mvals(jj) = mmax Then
        pos1.Value = pos(jj)
    End If
    If vvals(jj) = vmax Then
        pos2.Value = pos(jj)
    End If
Next jj


Sheets("Max Shear_Moment").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Try `pos.Cells(jj).value` instead of `pos(jj)`, you are trying to put a full range into a single cell's value.  Same with your if statements themselves.  use the `.cells(jj)`

Comment: @ScottCraner Hmm... just tried that and `pos(jj).Value` and neither worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
...
pos1 = -l    '<~~~
pos2 = -l    '<~~~

Dim jj As Long
For jj = 1 To NumRows
    If mvals(jj) = mmax Then
        pos1.Value = pos(jj)
    End If
    If vvals(jj) = vmax Then
        pos2.Value = pos(jj)
    End If
Next jj
```

`pos1` and `pos2` aren't `Range` objects any more, so they don't have a `.Value` property.

***Related:*** Best practice is to always refer directly to the property that you are trying to access like so:

```
Range("A1").Value = someVar
someOtherVar = Range("A1").Value
```

However, most objects have a *default* property - in the case of a `Range` object, it's *default* property is `.Value` and so if you refer to the object on it's own, the compiler will default to... well... the *default* property. So you could in theory do this:

```
Range("A1") = someVar
someOtherVar = Range("A1")
```

However there is no benefit to this (other than typing a few less characters) and it can cause undesired behaviour so it's generally not advised.

---

***Further Notes***

This is a perfect example of why you should always use `Option Explicit` when learning in VBA. Using this at the top of the module forces you to declare `Dim` all variables before use, meaning that not only do you get the added benefit of [intellisense](/questions/tagged/intellisense) but you would also not be able to assign a numeric value to `pos1` and `pos2` because they will have been declared as `Range` objects.

Comment: I changed `pos1 = -l` to `pos1.Value = -l` and it worked, but I still don't quite understand why...

l is defined as a Range, and so are pos1 and pos2

EDIT: wait a second... I think I understand, when I `Set l = Range("length")`, I'm setting it = to the value of Range("length"), which is an Integer Double or something?

Comment: Integer **or** Double

Comment: The `Set` keyword is used to set a reference to an object in memory, an object might be a `Range`, `Worksheet` or `Workbook` for example. To explain what's happening would require me to explain the difference between variables and object, what type-inference is and how variants work - which is a bit out of scope for this question. Basic thing you need to know at this point is simply **always use** `Option Explicit`

Comment: Downvoting till you explain =P

Comment: If you haven't declared the data type, `Set v = Range("A1")` will assign the actual `Range` object to `v`. Whereas `v = Range("A1")` will assign the default property of that range object (i.e. `.Value`) to `v` @findwindow - I had already written this before seeing your comment. Cheeky sausage...

Comment: <3 Edit: lol I didn't even follow through with my threat =P Guess it was unnecessary XD

Comment: That sort of makes sense... In this case I want `pos1` to be a range object because I want to both read the value of that cell and write to it... `l` on the other hand, simply needs to be the value from that range, so it could be defined without using `Set`. I think

Comment: `Dim pos1 As Range`/`Set pos1 = Range("A1")` for a range, for a whole number, best to use a `Long` data type. `Dim l As Long`/`l = Range("A1").Value`